# Verificar si son subconjunto y eliminarlos python

Tags: python-3.x, array, conjuntos

Les cuento que estoy en un curso de python versión 3 y nos dieron este ejercicio, lo hice por muchas horas y la verdad no me sale y soy nuevo en el lenguaje, el ejercicio consiste en:

Dadas dos listas de números "lista_a" y "lista_b", identificar si A es un subconjunto de B. Si es así, quitar todos los elementos de "lista_a" que existen en "lista_b".

les daré un ejemplo de lo que quiero que haga esta función:

```
lista_a = [4, 7, 2]

lista_b = [9, 4, 6, 2, 10, 7]

extraer_subconjunto(lista_a, lista_b)
```

así llamamos a la función y de resultado tendría que salir como resultado: [9, 6, 10]

Este es el código que hice pero no me sale el resultado:

```
def extraer_subconjunto(lista_a, lista_b):
lista_c = []
for i in lista_b:
    if i not in lista_a:
        lista_c.append(i)
    return lista_c
```

Me sale este resultado: [4, 7, 2, 9] que esta mal, espero puedan guiarme para encontrar la solución, muchas gracias

Comment: Perdon al escribir el código estaba ya medio cansado, no me di cuenta gracias pero igual el código sigue sin mostrar lo que me pide el problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema principal es el cuidar cómo indentas tu código, que es crucial en Python

Si yo lo edito levemente, así:

```
def extraer_subconjunto(lista_a, lista_b):
    lista_c = []

    for i in lista_b:
        if i not in lista_a:
            lista_c.append(i)
    return lista_c

lista_a = [4, 7, 2]
lista_b = [9, 4, 6, 2, 10, 7]

print(extraer_subconjunto(lista_a, lista_b))
```

Los cambios que estoy haciendo son:

- Al definir el método `extraer_subconjunto`, pongo el código propio del método indentado a la derecha, para indicar así que eso hace parte del método. Tú definías la `lista_c` al mismo nivel y eso la deja por fuera así que nada hacía el método. Todo se ejecutaba por fuera del método como parte del main y seguro ahí te daba ese resultado extraño.
- La instrucción `return` la ejecuto por fuera del ciclo `for x in`, porque necesitas que haga toooodo el ciclo for y luego retorne el resultado de iterar en todo el array. Así pues, el `return` se mueve cuatro espacios a la izquierda.

Sólo con ésto, tu código entrega el resultado esperado.

PD. Cuando preguntes, procura indicar qué versión de Python estás usando. Algunas cosas cambian de 2.7 a 3.x

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo logre haciendo las modificaciones que mencionaste, aun tengo que aprender a indentar bien

Answer (score 1):

hay otra manera usando conversiones, aunque menos pythonesca, te adjunto código con explicación

```html
#listas
A = [4, 7, 2]
B = [9, 4, 6, 2, 10, 7] 
# Convierto listas a set
AL=set(A)
BL=set(B)
# hago diferencia de set
CL=BL-AL
#convierto set a lisa
C=list(CL)
```

Comment: Yo considero esta forma más pythónica, especialmente si lo abrevias como `C = list(set(A)-set(B))`. Ahora bien, seguro que no era esta la solución que el profesor esperaba, si aún no se había explicado el tipo de datos `set()`.

Comment: si, queda mejor. Gracias

Comment: Gracias, otra interesante forma de resolver el problema, todavía no estoy familiarizado con la documentación de python pero muchas gracias